# User settings are not saved (Settings.Default.Save();)

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, application-settings

In the properties of project I created a setting like this

```
NumberOfUsers int User 10
```

The columns are Name, Type, Scope and Value.

Then there is a ComboBox where user can set a 'NumberOfUsers'. This combo has SelectedIndexChanged event where I save the changes whenever the user change the value of combo. Here's the code:

```
Settings.Default.NumberOfUsers = combo1.SelectedIndex;
Settings.Default.Save();
```

The form with this combo is called from the parent as `frm.ShowDialog();` and in Constructor of the child form I try to set combo's selected index based on the Settings entry

```
combo1.SelectedIndex = Settings.Default.NumberOfUsers;
```

However, this DOES NOT work, that is the combo does not pull the value from setting, but it rather defaults to 0 as selected index.

Anyone knows where I make mistake?

Comment: Are you sure the settings aren’t saved? Maybe it’s just the assignment to the combobox that’s not working. Use the debugger to break at the line `combo1.SelectedIndex = Settings.Default.NumberOfUsers` and check whether `NumberOfUsers` has the right value.

Comment: When I close the app, I open the project conf file and the Value box is still the default one. What does it mean? Problem with save after all?

Answer (score 6):

I think you do not make any mistake. As far as I know VS also regenarates the config file during the build. I would try it on a test machine.
It will store user settings in your user's AppData (local or roaming?) under something like this:

> AppData\[Local_or_Roaming]\YourCompanyName\yourprogram.exe_Url_[...]\1.0.0.0\user.config

The long foldername in the middle will be s.g. different but I guess you will find it easily. Have a look at this file and see if it stores the new values or not.

I use it many places and in the production environment it's working well. 
To be honest, on the dev machine I have never had it working.

Comment: Did not miss it because I have it in Using statement :)

Comment: OK, that's a possible way. :) 
Regarding your problem, did you check it in the AppData folder? As I mentioned user level settings are not stored in the exe.config file. Only the application level Settings are stored there.

Comment: "Losing" the user settings did not become a problem for me until I setup auto increment of the assembly version in the AssemblyInfo.cs file.  A new sub folder for the current assembly version is now generated for each build under "AppData\[Local_or_Roaming]\YourCompanyName\yourprogram.exe_Url_[...]\".  The new version subfolder also gets a new user.config.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that way:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.NumberOfUsers = combo1.SelectedIndex;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
combo1.SelectedIndex = Properties.Settings.Default.NumberOfUsers;
```

Comment: This is not the case as I have properties namespace in using statement

Answer (score 0):

Are you typing in the new value for NumberOfUsers in the ComboBox or selecting it from the drop down list?
If you type in the value SelectedIndex will not change so no event will be fired.

Also is the ComboBox being populated with values going from 0 to 10 or do you have code to handle ArgumentOutOfRangeExceptions